# Codeigniter $_GET in models?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a URL parameter I need to get to pass to a PHP MySQL Variable. 
Lets say for instance my URL is:

```
www.facebook.com/?ref=logo
```

Normally it'd $_GET to get the value of ref.  How would I go about doing this in a CodeIgniter model? From what I understand, $_GET doesn't work with CI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its in the input class.

```
 $ref = $this->input->get('ref');
```

Source : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 2):

Get works just fine in CodeIgniter. You would access it in a similar way to POST values:

```
$ref = $this->input->get('ref', true);
```